# gitolite permission denied for files I didn't change

Tags: gitolite

I'm in the process of migrating a project from SVN to Git/Gitolite and I'm getting an unexplained behavior.  The relevant portion of the config file is

```
repo ade
    RW                                     = jenkins matt
    -   dev/USER/master and VREF/NAME/ade/ = @grads
    RW+ dev/USER/                          = @all
    option hook.post-receive               = jenkins
```

which I believe means "Anyone can push to their own dev branch, as long as they don't touch any files in the ade/ directory and try to commit that to their personal master branch".  Is that right?  Well, ok, spoilers, that's not right, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

The problem is that when I run

```
git clone git@server:ade
git branch foo
git checkout foo
<<edit some file that's not in /ade/ and commit it>>
git push origin foo:dev/tom/foo
```

it says

```
remote: FATAL: W VREF/NAME/ade/filename.java ade tom DENIED by VREF/NAME/ade/
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/dev/tom/foo
```

and I don't know why.  Any ideas?

Edit:

Solved the problem... sorta.  I still don't know what I had been doing wrong, but I wrote a custom VREF that seems to do what I want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_output
import sys

if sys.argv[8] in sys.argv[1] and "/".join(sys.argv[9:]) in check_output(["git", "diff-tree", "--no-commit-id", "--name-only", "-r", sys.argv[3]]):
  print sys.argv[7]
```

Hopefully this'll save the next person a few hours of hair pulling.